# How to take out certain elements from a pdb file

Tags: bash, shell, perl, pdb-files

I am trying to take out certain columns from a pdb file. I already have taken out all lines that start out with ATOM in my code. For some reason my sub functions are not working and I do not know where or how to call them. 
My code is:

```
open (FILE, $ARGV[0])
    or die "Could not open file\n";

my @newlines;
 while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
    if ($line =~ m/^ATOM.*/) {
    push @newlines, $line;
    }
}

my $atomcount = @newlines;
#print "@newlines\n";
#print "$atomcount\n";

##############################################################
#This function will take out the element from each line
#The element is from column 77 and contains one or two letters

sub atomfreq {
    foreach my $record1(@newlines) {
      my $element = substr($record1, 76, 2);
      print "$element\n";
      return;
    }
}

################################################################
#This function will take out the residue name from each line
#The element is from column 18 and contains 3 letters

sub resfreq {
    foreach my $record2(@newlines) {
      my $residue = substr($record2, 17, 3);
      print "$residue\n";
      return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ossip already said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47724869/5830574) you simply need to call your functions:

```
sub atomfreq {
    ...
}

sub resfreq {
    ...
}

atomfreq();
resfreq();
```

**But** I'm not sure whether these functions do what you intended because the comments imply that they should print *every* `$residue` and `$element` from the `@newlines` array. You've put a `return` statement inside the `for` loop which will immediately return from the whole function (and its `for` loop) so it will print only the first `$residue` or `$element`. Because the functions aren't supposed to return anything you can just drop that statement:

```
sub atomfreq {
    foreach my $record1(@newlines) {
        my $element = substr($record1, 76, 2);
        print "$element\n";
    }
}

sub resfreq {
    foreach my $record2(@newlines) {
        my $residue = substr($record2, 17, 3);
        print "$residue\n";
    }
}

atomfreq();
resfreq();
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for the help. Also is it possible to count how much of each element there is and in alphabetical order within the same function??

Comment: Because you iterate over the complete `@newlines` there are exactly as many `$residue`s as there are elements in `@newlines`. No need to count them.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't make myself clear. The output of the atomfreq function contains letters such as C, O,N, and so on. How do i sort this to be in alphabetical order and count how C,O,N or other elements that are presented? Thanks again.

Comment: Well, that would be a new question but I can give you a hint: Store the `$residue` as the keys in a hash and increment the value by one in each iteration (as in `my %count; for ... { $residue=...; $count{$residue} += 1; }`).

Answer (score 1):

You can just call them right under your other code like this:

```
atomfreq();
resfreq();
```